# Cannot connect DynamoDB with Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Here is my code

```
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
dynamodb.batchGetItem(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else console.log(data); // successful response
});
```

and I got this error

```
{
    message: 'Could not load credentials from any providers',
    errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    code: 'CredentialsError',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: 'x.x.x.x',
    port: 80,
    time: 2019-03-13T07:59:34.279Z,
    originalError: {
        errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
        code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
        syscall: 'connect',
        address: 'x.x.x.x',
        port: 80,
        message: 'connect ETIMEDOUT x.x.x.x:80'
    }
}
```

I am new to AWS. I thought calling DynamoDB with Lambda do not need access and secret key. Is that correct?
I also grant full DynamoDB access permission role. What causes this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced the same problem here. The reason is your Lambda function seems inside a VPC and the DynamoDB isn't. Try removing the VPC in Network part of the settings and it should be solved.